# Vyatta Destination NAT not working

Tags: networking, nat, vyatta

We are running into an issue adding new IPs to a vyatta device after exceeding the limit of IPs in our first VRRP group.  All of the IPs listed in the `vrrp-group 1` work fine but any I add to `vrrp-group 2` do not.

We can see traffic coming in but the traffic we want to work (443) is never reaching NAT.  However, ping traffic comes in and returns (which should not work).  The NAT comes before the firewall but we've checked that to make sure we were not missing something and it has 0 hits.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Traffic comes in on port 443 but does not exit**

```
tcpdump: listening on bond1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
12:07:50.003063 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 52, id 63499, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
2.2.2.2.62111 > 1.1.1.1.443: Flags [S], cksum 0xd629 (correct), seq 237589496, win 65535, options [mss 1380,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1539048232 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:07:50.709156 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 52, id 37525, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
2.2.2.2.62113 > 1.1.1.1.443: Flags [S], cksum 0x412b (correct), seq 2830126052, win 65535, options [mss 1380,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1539048881 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:07:57.131533 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 52, id 34718, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
2.2.2.2.62137 > 1.1.1.1.443: Flags [S], cksum 0xc2c7 (correct), seq 3549136583, win 65535, options [mss 1380,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1539055166 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

**Nothing in NAT table of Firewall hits**

```
sh nat destination translations | match 1.1.1.1

sh firewall name out2in rule 100

-----------------------------
Rulesets Information
-----------------------------

IPv4 Firewall "out2in":

Active on traffic to -
zone [inside] from zone [outside]

rule action proto packets bytes
---- ------ ----- ------- -----
100 accept tcp 0 0
condition - saddr 0.0.0.0/0 daddr 10.0.0.100
```

**Ping works (but doesn't translate)**

```
15:11:31.052571 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 52, id 65344, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    2.2.2.2 > 1.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 28473, seq 117, length 64
15:11:31.052585 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9409, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    1.1.1.1 > 2.2.2.2: ICMP echo reply, id 28473, seq 117, length 64
15:11:32.055675 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 52, id 32001, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    2.2.2.2 > 1.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 28473, seq 118, length 64
```

**NAT**

```
set nat destination rule 100 destination address '1.1.1.1'
set nat destination rule 100 destination port 'https'
set nat destination rule 100 inbound-interface 'bond1'
set nat destination rule 100 protocol 'tcp'
set nat destination rule 100 translation address '10.0.0.100'
```

**Firewall**

```
set firewall name out2in rule 100 action 'accept'
set firewall name out2in rule 100 destination address '10.0.0.100'
set firewall name out2in rule 100 destination port '443'
set firewall name out2in rule 100 protocol 'tcp'
```

**VRRP Config**

```
set interfaces bonding bond1 address '1.1.1.4/28'
set interfaces bonding bond1 hash-policy 'layer3+4'
set interfaces bonding bond1 mode '802.3ad'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 1 advertise-interval '1'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 1 preempt 'false'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 1 priority '253'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 1 'rfc3768-compatibility'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 1 sync-group 'vgroup1'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 1 virtual-address '1.1.1.230/28'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 1 virtual-address '1.1.2.80/28'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 1 virtual-address '1.1.3.172/29'
...
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 2 advertise-interval '1'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 2 preempt 'false'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 2 priority '253'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 2 'rfc3768-compatibility'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 2 sync-group 'vgroup1'
set interfaces bonding bond1 vrrp vrrp-group 2 virtual-address '1.1.1.1/28'
```

**Added new subinterface to zone-policy**

```
set zone-policy zone outside interface 'bond1'
set zone-policy zone outside interface 'bond1v1'
set zone-policy zone outside interface 'bond1v2'
```

**Route matches similar routes in bond1v1**

```
1.1.3.172/28 is directly connected, bond1v1
1.1.1.1/28 is directly connected, bond1v2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured this out.  The issue is actually with my internal network 10.0.0.100 which appears not to be working properly.